# How to call a modal from a different HTML File

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask, bootstrap-4

I realise there are similar questions on stackoverflow, however they either seem outdated(bootstrap3) or are not working for me. If possible I want to just stick to html css and javascript. I would prefer not using jquery or php.

I'll keep my code very general. I have my **mainscreen** which has a button I need that button to call a modal from **ModalPage**. ModalPage only has that modal with no other code. I'm using flask-python as my backend.

**Mainscreen**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">This should call modal/button>
```

**ModalPage**

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried using `url_for` and rendering it using `<a>` but that doesn't seem to be working

Comment: What kind of framework are you using? Using pure js/html/css there is no built in modal functionality

Comment: @MauriceNino Yes it's pure html css and javascript. But I'm using flask

Comment: I don't think the "backend" is of any relevance here. To display/hide a modal you'll need to write some Javascript code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: is your modal page loaded into page? do you see the code of modalpage in your dev tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to store the entire modal HTML in a variable within your Python Flask code. One way (out of quite a few number of ways) would be to read the text and store the html in a variable using:

```
modaltext=[]
with open('ModalPage.html', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
    modaltext.append(content)
```

Put this above code in your views.py preferably. That filename depends on where you have stored the ModalPage.html. Here I assumed, it is in the same folder as views.py (which might not be the case. It could be in templates, but I dunno your folder structure).

And modify your `return render` statement to also return the `modaltext` list.

Then, call it to your Mainpage HTML using jinja2 syntax wherever necessary. Typically it could be like:

```
<div>{{ modal }}</div>
```

Comment: I don't know if this is an efficient way of doing it. Is there a better method by using pure html, css and javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I'm honestly not sure about the python/flask portion, but I do what you are attempting using only html/js. You could add an ID to the button, i.e 'modal-form-button'. Then make an event listener in JS for the element with that ID being clicked.

```
document.getElementById("test-btn").addEventListener("click", showModal);
```

The showModal() function can contain the necessary code to toggle the display of the modal between 'display:bloack' and 'display:none'

Comment: he asked vanilla JS, not jQuery

Comment: Edited to match the requirements of the posted question.

Comment: @EzeWinzAgain In this doesn't the modal need to be on the same page? How am I linking it to the modal on another page?

Comment: After some research, again never used flask-python, it looks like you will need to setup an app.route for the GET serverside. Client side the js function would fetch the data from that route. Once successfully retrieved, depending on the return data, you can add that content to the DOM with JS. I found the following two articles helpful, although the second is jquery specific:
[Talking Between Languages](https://healeycodes.com/javascript/python/beginners/webdev/2019/04/11/talking-between-languages.html) [jquery-flask-tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/jquery-flask-tutorial/)

Comment: @rishi I forgot to specifically mention that it looks like your server side endpoint needs to return render_template('ModalPage.html') I believe. I am not 100% on what format this will be on the client side. You can log the response to the console on success, and handle it accordingly with your JS.

Comment: @WeWillDevelop This doesn't seem to be working. I'm probably doing something incorrectly

Comment: @rishi Any specific part not working? If you set up the server side endpoint, and call to it from js, are you getting to it? That would be my primary goal out the gate. Even if the endpoint is returning nothing at first. Once you can hit that endpoint from client side, I would then worry about the html rendering and adding the content to the DOM.